# How to combine multiple columns into one column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm writing a query and want the results in one column 
My current results return like this

```
Column1     Column2    column3
1              A         CAT
```

I want the results to return like this

```
Column1
1
A
CAT
```

Comment: You need `Unpivot`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
SELECT Column1 FROM TableName
UNION ALL
SELECT Column2 FROM TableName
UNION ALL
SELECT Column3 FROM TableName
```

If you don't want duplicate values, use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`.

You can also do this using `UNPIVOT` operator

```
SELECT Column123
FROM
(
  SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 
  FROM TableName
) AS tmp
UNPIVOT 
(
  Column123 FOR ColumnAll IN (Column1, Column2, Column3)
) AS unpvt;
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3000/use-sql-servers-unpivot-operator-to-help-normalize-output/

Answer (score 2):

The answer is.. it depends..

If the number of columns are unknown.. then use unpivot as UZI has suggested

if you know all columns and is a small finite set..

you can simply go

```
Select
column1
from table

union all
select column2
from table

union all
select column3
from table
```

Answer (score 2):

**The Cartesian product of the T table with derived table of 3 rows.(each row of #t is presented 3 times, for а=1 and а=2 and а=3). For the first case we take value from Column1, 
and for the second - from Column2 and for the Third - from Column3.
Here, certainly, there is both union and join but, in my opinion, the title's question means single scanning the table.**

```
CREATE TABLE #t (Column1 NVARCHAR(25),Column2 NVARCHAR(25), column3 NVARCHAR(25))

INSERT INTO #t
SELECT '1','A','CAT'

SELECT
CASE a WHEN 1 THEN Column1  WHEN 2 THEN Column2 ELSE column3 END col
FROM #t, (SELECT 1 a UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) B

DROP TABLE #t
```